# How to create dynamic where conditions according to the parameter in stored procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure in which I want to list employees according to the parameter. 
The procedure has some parameters, one of them I want to use for the type(eg:branch, department etc) and the other is the id corresponding to that.

I want to create where conditions to variable.

How can I do that?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE Emp_details(IN div_type VARCHAR(100), IN id INT, OUT emp_name VARCHAR(100)) 
BEGIN 

        DECLARE cond VARCHAR(100);

        IF div_type = 'branch' THEN
            SET cond = 'branch_id='+id;
        ELSEIF div_type = 'department' THEN
            SET cond = 'department_id='+id;
        ELSEIF div_type = 'emp' THEN
            SET cond = 'employee_master_id='+id;
        ELSE
            SET cond = '';
        END IF;                                                                                    


        SELECT
         emp_fullname INTO emp_name
            FROM armr_employee_master
        WHERE +cond ;



END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just turn the `IF` into a `WHERE`:

```
SELECT emp_fullname
INTO emp_name
FROM armr_employee_master
WHERE id = CASE div_type
    WHEN 'branch' THEN branch_id
    WHEN 'department' THEN department_id
    WHEN 'emp' THEN employee_master_id
END
```

Comment: I tried this but not working.. When calling Emp_details('branch',3) I want to return all the employee names where branch_id=3. @Bohemian